# Using a printer to print Unity3D Game statistics

Tags: c#, printing, unity-game-engine

For a museum we're producing a collection of different minigames and a maingame, that uses the results of the minigames as a resource. When the visitor exits the museum, he should be able to print a summary of his game actions, mainly in form of statistics.

The station, where he should be able to print this, is running an Unity3D application. The statistic contains text as well as graphical elements (pie charts) that is colored.

Is there a way to print such informations from within a Unity3D Application? Or should I focus on another solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Unity3D doesn't handle printing directly, you can either:

- [Write your own C# printing algorithm](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552912%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) or use an existing one.
- [Write your own Unity Plugin](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html) or use an [existing one](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/8437).

If you need to support only Windows, you'll probably be better off by just saving the text to a file (.txt, .pdf, etc.) and then have it printed using the .NET Framework.

Comment: I'll discuss this with our customers - the (only) existing one seems to print only Texture2Ds, not text. So I either need a custom Plugin or a "Design function" that put's the text as we want it to an Texture2D.

Comment: If you need to support only Windows, you'll be better off by just saving the text to a file (.txt, .pdf, etc.) and then have it printed using the .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that Unity API allows using printer devices, but you can easily develop your own [custom native plugin](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForDesktop.html) that will take data from your game and print it just as any other desktop application for your target platform would.